# PySpark 2: KMeans The input data is not directly cached

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, k-means

I don't know why I receive the message

```
WARN KMeans: The input data is not directly cached, which may hurt performance if its parent RDDs are also uncached.
```

When I try to use Spark `KMeans`

```
df_Part = assembler.transform(df_Part)    
df_Part.cache()
while (k<=max_cluster) and (wssse > seuilStop):
                    kmeans = KMeans().setK(k)
                    model = kmeans.fit(df_Part)
                    wssse = model.computeCost(df_Part)
                    k=k+1
```

It says that my input (Dataframe) is not cached !!

I tried to print df_Part.is_cached and I received True which means that my dataframe is cached, So why Spark still warns me about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This message is generated by the `o.a.s.mllib.clustering.KMeans` and there is nothing you can really about it without patching Spark code.

Internally `o.a.s.ml.clustering.KMeans`:

- Converts `DataFrame` to `RDD[o.a.s.mllib.linalg.Vector]`.
- Executes `o.a.s.mllib.clustering.KMeans`.

While you cache `DataFrame`, `RDD` which is used internally is not cached. This is why you see the warning. While it is annoying I wouldn't worry to much about it.

Answer (score 2):

This was fixed in Spark 2.2.0.  Here is the [Spark-18356](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18356).

The discussion there also suggests this is not a big deal, but the fix may reduce runtime slightly, as well as avoiding warnings.

Comment: Thanks, that was me :)  who create that topic in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18356

Comment: I am using Spark 2.3.0 with Python 3.5.2 and the warning is still there