# Pyspark - WARN BisectingKMeans: The input RDD is not directly cached

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I'm running bisecting kmeans as

```
bkm_test=BisectingKMeans().setK(5).setSeed(1)

rdf.cache()
assembled.cache()
model_test=bkm_test.fit(assembled)
```

I cached the two dataframes as I keep getting the error, but it doesn't make a difference, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406166/pyspark-2-kmeans-the-input-data-is-not-directly-cached) which is similar but with kmeans.
But I also get a WARN Executor error below. Is this only something inside the algorithm that I can't fix?

```
17/08/14 21:53:17 WARN BisectingKMeans: The input RDD 306 is not directly cached, which may hurt performance if its parent RDDs are also not cached.
17/08/14 21:53:17 WARN Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 132:
[rdd_302_0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes from [BisectingKMeans within MLlib](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/BisectingKMeans.scala#L159-L162), which [Spark ML uses internally](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/clustering/BisectingKMeans.scala#L272). MLlib uses RDDs of vectors, while Spark ML is DataFrame oriented, so the ML version of BisectingKMeans [converts your DataFrame into an RDD of Vector values](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/clustering/BisectingKMeans.scala#L259). The conversion isn't cached, so you end up getting the error.

Hopefully, this isn't a major slowdown. I haven't found an easy way to force the caching of the converted RDD.